# Android application with pytorch

Tags: android, server, pytorch

I made some andorid application. Also I have python files that take some jpg files as input and return some values. These python files use pytorch library. How can I run my python files in android application?

Comment: Can this help you?
https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques for running on Android, and the best choice will depend on your use case.

If your application does not require the faster speed of GPU inference, [Pytorch Mobile](https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/) will be easiest.

If you need to use GPU, you'll need to convert your model to run on a different framework. [Tensorflow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) is popular for Android deployment. If you're primarily targeting Qualcomm devices, you may find a speed boost by running on the [Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine (SNPE)](https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/overview.html).